# How to conveniently extract single response cookies from a shared static HttpClient without mixing cookies from other parallel requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies

I'm working on a web application that needs to proxy some requests to some other internal website.

I'm using a shared static HTTP client instance to avoid performance issues, according to these articles:

https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/
https://medium.com/@nuno.caneco/c-httpclient-should-not-be-disposed-or-should-it-45d2a8f568bc

Obviously, I don't want to blindly store cookies coming back from HttpClient and then blindly send them back because that would mess up cookies coming from different web requests to my website. So, I have turned cookie usage off:

```
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    // make sure we don't share cookies 
    // when sending requests over our shared HttpClient instance
    UseCookies = false,

    // if API returns a redirect, we want to let the caller handle it
    AllowAutoRedirect = false,
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip
};
var apiClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
```

However, there are situations when I need to extract and process cookies from a specific HttpClient web request in my web app.

I can see the required cookies present in HttpResponseMessage headers:

```
var setCookieHdr = response.Headers.GetValues("set-cookie");
```

The problem - setCookieHdr is a string and not a convenient CookieCollection.

**Is there any simple and thread-safe way to turn the "set-cookie" header into a CookieCollection?**

I have seen examples using

```
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.CookieContainer = cookies;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("http://google.com").Result;

Uri uri = new Uri("http://google.com");
IEnumerable<Cookie> responseCookies = cookies.GetCookies(uri).
```

but I highly suspect that such approach would lead to race conditions. The handler could have stored the last cookie value coming from a parallel proxy-ed HttpClient response and not the response my proxy controller method is currently working on, because HttpClient is a shared static instance, together with the handler and its CookieContainer.

I need to extract cookies just from this specific response and not mess with any current cookies of the shared static HttpClient - those cookies should be ignored completely to avoid mixing them for multiple parallel requests.

Comment: Don't use a single `HttpClient` for everything. Use `IHttpClientFactory`. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @ChrisPratt  thanks, I'll look into that option;  but I'm not sure if that would deal with response cookies because I would never be sure if the HttpClient instance I'm getting is a new one with empty cookies or a pooled one with some cookies coming from parallel responses (unless CookieContainer or HttpClientHandler is guaranteed to be race-condition safe and non-pooled).

Comment: Yes, per named client. `IHttpClientHandler` actually creates an `HttpMesageHandler` instance per name (it's essentially a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, HttpMessageHandler>`). A transient `HttpClient` is returned with it's message handler set to the named handler that was requested. You can also do "typed" clients, which are based on the type they're being injected into, but this is really just a named client, under the hood. The long and short, is that you should have one named client per unique usage scenario.

Comment: Well, then it would not solve the issue because I have multiple parallel requests calling a proxy to exact same resource - so it would be a single named instance of HttpClient. The problem is that when a response returns from the same client, I must be sure I collect cookies (which are unique per request) exactly from the current response and not some parallel response of the same named HttpClient.

Comment: The cookies belong to the response, not the client. The response will be unique per request. The only problem would be if you then attempted to do something like set `DefaultRequestHeaders` with the cookie, which would impact all further requests with that client. Just create an `HttpRequestMessage` and attach the cookie to that, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Regardless, you should still be using `IHttpClientFactory`, whether it directly solves this particular issue or not.

Comment: But CookieContainer.GetCookies(uri) seems to get all cookies per uri of the (singleton) handler and there's no way to tell it to extract cookies for currently scoped request. I'm not sure if CookieContainer can automagically limit itself to current response only and not some parallel response, if there is no visible way to attach it to a specific response? Is there any proof of that?